# Empty grey tiles in map

Tags: android, android-mapview

I made an mapActivity with the key that someone gave me. But when I run it, it showed only grey tiles but when I asked them, they said its showing fine there. What could be the problem, why is it not showing here in my side.?

Comment: are you sure you are signing the app with the same keystore which was used to create the api key?

Comment: I must be missing what u said. I'll try this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

becuase key is generated by other keystore  and  you need to go here

[Sign Up for the Android Maps API - Android Maps API - Google Code](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup)

and generate your on Maps API key.

and second option you must sign the app with the same keystore with which was used to create the Map API Key.